# ajax isn't getting called when submit button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form with a submit button and I am trying to get an ajax call to work that will display a spinner on the screen to let the user know that the form is working on submitting the information. From what I can tell, the form is never even calling the ajax and I can't figure out why.

This is the form (shortened to the submit button section):

```
<form id="generateDocumentForm" action="/Documents/GenerateDocument" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
     <div>
         <div class="RcmDialogBody">
            "This just has text boxes and things of that nature"
         </div>   


         <div class="form-actions">
             <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="btn btn-primary" />       <-----This is the button I am trying to use to call the ajax
             <button type="button" onclick="hideModal()" class="btn">Cancel</button>
         </div>  
     </div>
</form>
```

This is the ajax that isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("generateDocumentForm").submit(function(){
            var docspinner;
            docspinner = new Spinner()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Documents/GenerateDocument",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    if (docspinner) {
                        alert('has spinner!');

                        if(docspinner.hasOwnProperty('show'))
                            alert('has show!');
                    }
                    docspinner.show('Working');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    docspinner.hide();
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    alert('done!');
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        notify.success({ header: 'Document Generated!' });
                    } else {
                        notify.warn({ header: 'Error Generating Document!' });
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (!checkAndHandleAjaxAccessDenied(xhr.responseText)) {
                        notify.error({ header: 'Error' });
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: `$("generateDocumentForm").submit` should be `$("#generateDocumentForm").submit`. Also, what is `/Documents/GenerateDocument` is that suppose to be a file? are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Also, action="/Documents/GenerateDocument" method="POST" are redundant given that you are handling the form submit using Javascript.

Comment: @sriniprash not redundant at all if user has javascript disabled. Where it it post to then?

Comment: Need to prevent the default browser submit of form when using ajax.http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @imtheman : Yes, That `/Documents/GenerateDocument` is for a file. and no I am not receiving any errors in my console. I wish I was because then I might be able to debug this issue easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$("generateDocumentForm").submit` to `$("#generateDocumentForm").submit`

Remember that hastags are important! :) Otherwise everything else in your code looks pretty solid. Hope this helps!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#generateDocumentForm").submit(function(e){ //added hastag to properly grab the form by id
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default submission by the browser. Without this the ajax call will fail because your page will reload each time, explained in comments as well
            var docspinner;
            docspinner = new Spinner()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Documents/GenerateDocument",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    if (docspinner) {
                        alert('has spinner!');

                        if(docspinner.hasOwnProperty('show'))
                            alert('has show!');
                    }
                    docspinner.show('Working');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    docspinner.hide();
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    alert('done!');
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        notify.success({ header: 'Document Generated!' });
                    } else {
                        notify.warn({ header: 'Error Generating Document!' });
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (!checkAndHandleAjaxAccessDenied(xhr.responseText)) {
                        notify.error({ header: 'Error' });
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that type-o but i still cannot get the spinner to appear. I even changed its z-index to an unnecessarily high number to ensure it wasn't hidden behind anything.

Comment: what spinner plugin are you using?

Comment: The team I am on created their own spinner class before I joined on and they have used it on other forms so I know the class itself works. For some reason, I can't get it to work here.

Comment: well since it is a custom API I would not be familiar with it nor would I probably be able to give you an answer that would be satisfactory on that subject. Your best bet would be just to ask one of them for the help. I'm sure it's just something with the placement, it probably wouldn't take long for them to identify it. Sorry I couldn't be help on this matter :/

Comment: It's all good. The rest of my team is currently on vacation for the holidays so I've been trying to work it out myself and finally posted on here to see if anyone had any suggestions. I may just have to wait for them to get back so they can look at it. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: also don't forget to accept the answer if it is satisfactory

Comment: OK. It still hasn't solved my issue, but I will go ahead and accept it because it would probably solve issues for others since most people that see this questions won't have the unusually difficult time that I am having. lol